# Restrict directory access directly entering it in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to restrict direct access to my website by entering url directly in browser in php.
Actually i search many more, all are saying use .htaccess file
but i want to restrict only those user which are entering that url directly in browser

Example:

my website having directory "payment" which is used for payment process.
when any user does shopping then my website automatically will go to that directory for payment process but if any one enters that same url in browser i want to restrict that and redirect it to home page

please help me
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a variable to say your user has the right to enter a part of your website.

For example : `$_SESSION['access_page']['payment'] = true;`

Then, you check this variable when a user loads a page and redirect him if necessary (or 403).